# How can I make my picture display on a half of the screen?

Tags: html, css, image

I want my picture display on a half of the screen when device has a width more than 540px. But my code doesn't work. What's wrong?

```html
<picture>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dtQLbqkK/photo-2020-10-08-12-15-49.jpg 426w" sizes="(min-width: 540px) 50vw">
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/4drQ8YNZ/photo-2020-10-08-12-06-49.jpg 1280w 3x, https://i.postimg.cc/SsWnhRfm/photo-2020-10-08-12-14-56.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 540px) 50vw">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine directly set with css as followed:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px){
  picture{
    width: 100vw;
  }
  img, source{
    min-width: 50vw;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dtQLbqkK/photo-2020-10-08-12-15-49.jpg 426w" sizes="(min-width: 540px) 50vw">
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/4drQ8YNZ/photo-2020-10-08-12-06-49.jpg 1280w 3x, https://i.postimg.cc/SsWnhRfm/photo-2020-10-08-12-14-56.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 540px) 50vw">
</picture>
```