# How can I make my picture appear correctly?

Tags: html, css, image

I have two pictures: small and big youtube logo. I want my big youtube logo display when the width of my screen is more than 600px. And I want my small youtube logo display when the width of my screen is less than 600px.

**!Also my big logo have to be on a half of the screen.** But there's the problem. When I establish to my big logo some properties to make it behave this way, this logo stopes display at all.

Here's my code:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/L5hRsX4B/youtube-logo-font.jpg" media="(min-width: 600px) 50vw">
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/yN7Mddvg/Logo-youtube-ios-cropped.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yN7Mddvg/Logo-youtube-ios-cropped.jpg" alt="photo-youtube">
</picture>
```

What did cause this bahaviour? And how can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make my picture display on a half of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308020/how-can-i-make-my-picture-display-on-a-half-of-the-screen)

Comment: @MaxiGui maybe, but I was more interested to did this only with html and figure out why my code above works this way

Comment: then try with 5w instead of vw as vw is not aken correctly anyway on media

Answer (score 1):

It works fine directly set with css media query as followed:

Demo

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
  picture{
    width: 100vw;
  }
  img, source{
    min-width: 50vw;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/L5hRsX4B/youtube-logo-font.jpg" media="(min-width: 600px) 50vw">
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/yN7Mddvg/Logo-youtube-ios-cropped.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yN7Mddvg/Logo-youtube-ios-cropped.jpg" alt="photo-youtube">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it! There is the thing that I mixed up with 2 attributes: `media` and `sizes`. They work differently. We should establish `media` attribute **without** desired width of element. For example:

```
media="(min-width:650px)"
```

And we can establish `sizes` attribute **with** the width of our element. For example:

```
sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px"
```

And also this attribute can work like this. This example shows that we have to establish the desired width of our element in `sizes` attribute. It's necessary!

```
sizes="280px"
```

We can use `media` if we want to replace some pictures. And we can use `sizes` if we want our pictures responsive. There's no html property which can solve this problem. So, the best way is using CSS (or JS) aditionally.

Answer (score 0):

for this project you should put media="max-width:600px" and run project.

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/L5hRsX4B/youtube-logo-font.jpg" media="(min-width: 600px)  ">
  <source srcset="https://i.postimg.cc/yN7Mddvg/Logo-youtube-ios-cropped.jpg" media="(max-width:600px)">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yN7Mddvg/Logo-youtube-ios-cropped.jpg" alt="photo-youtube">
</picture>
```

Comment: i can't delete it please explain